# Lie algebra of a Lie group (a question from PSE)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, tangent-spaces

I'm going through some notes on group theory for physics. After introducing the concept of Lie group and Lie algebra the writer makes the connection between the two.

Let $G$ be a Lie group of endomorphism of a vector space $V$, he defines the set of all curves $\gamma(t)$ of $G$ through the identity as $\mathcal{C}_G$ *such that $\gamma(0)=1_V$*. Then shows that the derivative of a curve in $\mathcal{C}_G$ evaluated at $0$ is still an endomorphism.

Then define a set as
$$
\mathfrak{g}=\left\{X \in \text{End}(V)\text{ s.t. }\exists\gamma \in \mathcal{C}_G \text{ with }X=d\gamma(0)/dt\right\}
$$
and then shows that this set $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie subalgebra of the general linear algebra $\mathfrak{gl}$. With this last theorem the chapter finishes and moves to the next topic.

---

I'm getting confused on two points:

1. can the set $\mathfrak{g}$ be identified as the tangent space to the identity?
2. the last theorem shows that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie subalgebra of the general linear algebra $\mathfrak{gl}$. Being a subalgebra it is also an algebra, but I don't get why it's the Lie algebra of the group $G$.

I hope I've been clear enough, otherwise I'm happy to add details.

Edit: I've had some details on how the curve is defined, I marked them in italic so it's easier to spot them, and rephrased the question.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is exactly. Are you asking, What is the identification of $T_e G$ and the space $\mathfrak{g} \subset \operatorname{End}(V)$?

Comment: @TravisWillse I've had some details on how the curve is defined, I marked them in italic so it's easier to spot them, and rephrased the question.

Comment: There is no such thing as the identity of a vector space. Surely you mean the identity of $G$.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes you're right, my bad

Comment: @TravisWillse I think so. Sorry but I'm a physicist and sometimes I get confused on the math. In the end, is it correct to identify $\mathfrak{g}$ with the tangent space to the identity, right?

Comment: Yes, in fact there's a canonical identification (i.e., one that doesn't involve any arbitrary choices).